# Pickup script assigning variable and updating text

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to set text from Pickup script assigning variable and updating text in script on UI, but it's working only on one object, on others text isn't showing.

Maybe someone can see the problem?

Pickup script:

```
public enum Items
{
    Garbage,
    Dishes,
    Water,
    Milk
}

void Update()
{
    float dist = Vector3.Distance(playerTransform.position, transform.position);

    if (dist <= radius)
    {
        string txt = item.ToString();
        displayTxt = "Press E to Collect " + txt;
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E)) displayTxt = "";
    }
    else
        displayTxt = "";
}
```

Tooltip script:

```
public static Text textObject;
public static string textValue = "";

void Start()
{
    textObject = GetComponent<Text>();
}

void Update()
{
    textValue = PickupItem.displayTxt;
    textObject.text = textValue;
}
```

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than on other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Why are your fields **[`static`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static#example---static-field-and-method)**?

> ```
> public static Text textObject;
> public static string textValue = "";
> ```

Basically all instances of your script are using the same "shared" (in fact it doesn't belong to any instance at all but rather the type itself) field `textObject`.

They all overwrite it at the beginning via

```
textObject = GetComponent<Text>();
```

so whichever instance is executing `Start` last "wins" and overwrites the `textObject` with its own `Text` component. From now on all instances update only that one with a new text.

=> Remove the `static` and you are probably fine

```
public Text textObject;
public string textValue = "";
```